# Malloc using more memory than specified?

Tags: c

I'm allocating memory for a string using malloc: `s=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*4)`
Why can I store more than 4 characters to the string? If I allocated 4 bytes of memory and each character requires 1 byte, why can I store 8 characters before the program crashes?

Comment: From a language perspective: most things you can do wrong in C trigger undefined behaviour instead of a specific behaviour like crashing. Undefined behaviour means that anything can happen, including appearing to work for some values or for some amount of time.

Comment: 1) Undefined behavior is... well, undefined. 2) malloc may allocate more than requested for alignment, housekeeping, or other reasons.

Comment: @Ry-: “Undefined” in the C standard does not mean anything can happen.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: "Anything can happen" in my comment does not mean anything can happen.

Comment: @Ry-: People learning a new subject are not helped by false statements. You may know what you mean, but a student has to learn many other things before they can figure out that your statement is literally false and you meant something else. Tell the truth. Do not write statements you know to be false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: From the spec: "**undefined behavior**: behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements"  -- anything can happen.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: No, that does not mean anything can happen. It merely says the C standard does not say what happens. It does not, and cannot, revoke the specifications of the C implementation, the operating system, the hardware components. Nor can it revoke consumer protection laws, physical limits, or other constraints outside the C standard. Many C implementations provide extensions to the C standard (which the standard allows as conforming) that define behaviors the C standard does not. If “undefined” meant “anything can happen,” those extensions could not be defined.

Comment: It it precisely "undefined" meaning "anything can happen" that *allows* those other things to be defined.  If it did not, they could not (or at least it would be much harder to define vendor-specific extensions to the language)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: People learning a new subject don’t choose the least charitable face value interpretation of idioms, ignoring context like "from a language perspective".

Comment: @Ry-: Write true statements. Do not write false statements.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: “it precisely "undefined" meaning "anything can happen" that allows those other things to be defined.’: No, an assertion that anything can happen is inconsistent with the fact that other specifications still control what can happen. It is **false** that anything can happen because there are other specifications and constraints on what can happen. If the C standard asserted that anything can happen, it would be overriding those other specifications. It cannot do that and it does not do that. "Undefined” is a surrender of control, not an overriding of control.

Comment: You seem to be claiming that "anything can happen" precludes certain things from happening, if those things happen to be thought of by anyone else.  That's a strange definition of "anything" in my book, but at this point we're arguing about the meaning of english words, not about anything in any standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it i(in some cases) but this results in 'Undefined Behavior'. UB can produce many results, including seeming to work most of the time until your biggest customer tries to run your app on their busiest day.

You must not do this. There are various tools that you can use to detect it (electric fence, valgrind, for example)